# Move from top-left to bottom-right in hover

Tags: html, css

is it possible to move element from top-left to bottom-right in
something like this:
 [image]

```css
#example {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
  right: auto;
  bottom: auto;
}

#example:hover {
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0
}
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: Are you looking for css only solution or jquery/javascript is ok?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes...and no.

The problem is that your div will move once you hover it and so as soon as it moves from under the cursor will stop being hovered and the hover state will fail.

So, you have to move the hover to another element (perhaps the `body`).

BUT you can't transition `left` to `right` (or to/from `auto`) so you'd have to adjust the position of the element with a transform.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#example {
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
}
body:hover #example {
  left: 100%;
  top: 100%;
  transform: translate(-100%, -100%)
}
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

Note: If the height/width of the element is *known* you can use `calc` as well and avoid the transform.

```
body:hover #example {
    left:calc(100% - 40px);
    top:calc(100% - 40px);
```

}

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#example {
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    transition: all 300ms ease 0s;
}
body:hover #example {
    left:calc(100% - 40px);
    top:calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

```html
<div id="example"></div>
```

Comment: thanks Paulie, which one is better and faster ? cal or transform ?

Comment: Probably about the same...it's a minimal transition...the transform works regardless of the start /end height/width etc (and which browsers you want to support as it's CSS3) whereas the second requires you know sizes - http://jsfiddle.net/PvfFy/526/